# Error: "Parse Error at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1583:20)" while using mocha framework in node.js

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am using mocha framework for writing test cases in node.js, all the test cases work fine except update test case for a particular method.
Here is my code:

```
it("should update market if exists", function(done) {
  var market = {
    name: 'market name updated',
    description: 'description is updated'
  }
  request('http://localhost:3000')
    .put('/admin/product/chairs')
    .send(market)
    .expect(200, done);
});
it("should not update market", function(done) {
  var market = {
    name: 'market name updated',
    description: 'description is updated'
  }
  request('http://localhost:3000')
    .put('/admin/product/chai')
    .send(market)
    .expect(404, done);
});
```

In second case I am giving wrong URL to get 404 response but got this.
Error: Parse Error
    at Socket.socketOnData (http.js:1583:20)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:527:27)

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue here was? I am getting the same error now.

Comment: Hi @Jason yup I got it, this is because of null reference parsing, somewhere mocha gets blank string or null value and troubles with it and throws parsing error.
Just checkout your code, and you 'll get it.